# Como fazer um CASE WHEN para expressões nomeadas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia!

Estou com problema em fazer um `CASE WHEN` de uma expressão nomeada. Eu tenho um `SELECT` no qual um dos parâmetros possui uma expressão nomeada.

Exemplo:

```sql
ROUND(NFI.NOTAFISCALITEM_VALORMARGEMGERENCIAL, 2))MARGEM
```

Eu quero fazer uma verificação para que esta expressão não retorne valores `NULL`. Eu tentei fazer assim:

```sql
CASE WHEN (ROUND(NFI.NOTAFISCALITEM_VALORMARGEMGERENCIAL, 2)MARGEM) <> NULL THEN MARGEM ELSE 0 END
```

Mas, dessa forma recebo um erro dizendo o seguinte:

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'MARGEM'.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Presumindo que o que postou esteja na SELECT List ou na cláusula WHERE veja o que diz o manual: "It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.". Contudo se você apenas deseja que apareça 0 quando o campo for NULL utilize a função COALESCE: `COALESCE(ROUND(NFI.NOTAFISCALITEM_VALORMARGEMGERENCIAL, 2), 0) AS MARGEM`

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado! coloca o que você disse como resposta pra eu dar o Check

Answer (score 1):

Coloque um `AS` (AS "significa alias, podemos chamar de um outro nome uma determinada tabela ou coluna utilizando um 'alias'") antes de `MARGEM`

```
ROUND(NFI.NOTAFISCALITEM_VALORMARGEMGERENCIAL, 2) AS MARGEM
```

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isso mas ele retorna o seguinte erro: "SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Answer (score -2):

```
CASE WHEN (ROUND(NFI.NOTAFISCALITEM_VALORMARGEMGERENCIAL, 2)MARGEM) 
     <> NULL THEN MARGEM,
     ELSE
        0
     END AS MARGEM
FROM tabela
WHERE id > 0;
```